# Sort lists in a nested list based on the argsort of the 0th list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, numpy

What's the neatest way to sort a nest of list based on the first list in the list?

before sort

```
>>> list_of_things = [[100,300,200],[t,u,v]]
```

after sort

```
>>> [[100,200,300],[t,v,u]]
```

So far using search I've located an index I can use to sort

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sort_index=np.argsort(list_of_things[0])
```

But I haven't found a pythonic way to index both sublists on sort_index.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Comment: You want to sort list[1:n] based on the argsorted values of list[0]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(arr) 
array([['100', '300', '200'],
       ['t', 'u', 'v']],
      dtype='<U21')
```

First, `argsort` the 0<sup>th</sup> list:

```
idx = np.argsort(arr[0])

print(idx)
array([0, 2, 1])
```

Now, just use `numpy indexing`:

```
arr = arr[:, idx]

print(arr)
array([['100', '200', '300'],
       ['t', 'v', 'u']],
      dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a tool from [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library that sorts iterables in parallel.

First install the library:

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

**Code**

```
from more_itertools import sort_together


iterables = [[100, 300, 200], ["t", "u", "v"]]
sort_together(iterables)
# [(100, 200, 300), ('t', 'v', 'u')]
```

All iterables are sorted by the a 0-th index by default.  This sorting priority can be adjusted by the `key_list` parameter.

See [`more_itertools` docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sort_together) for details.